# Crypto.Cipher AES.MODE_EAX encrypt_and_digest error: argument 2 must be bytes, not bytearray

Tags: aes, pycrypto

The following code gave me the error "argument 2 must be bytes, not bytearray".  I can't find any doc about encrypt_and_digest except some example codes which all just passed one argument to the method. Anyone knows what's the issue here?  Thanks.

```
key = rb(16)
cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_EAX)
ciphertext, tag = cipher.encrypt_and_digest(b'hello')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I traced the error source to the third line in the following code

```
partial = self._cache[:]
partial[self._cache_n:] = b'\x80' + b'\x00' * (bs - self._cache_n - 1)
pt = strxor(strxor(self._last_ct, partial), self._k2)
```

in the function digest in the file python3.7/site-packages/Crypto/Hash/CMAC.py. 
The error is about the second argument partial, which is a bytearray. When I modified the third line to the following, the error went away.

```
pt = strxor(strxor(self._last_ct, bytes(partial)), self._k2)
```

Answer (score 4):

Most probably you have installed both the pycryptodome and the old pycrypto packages.

Run "pip uninstall pycrypto" and try again.

For further details see
https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/faq.html